# Secondary monitor problems

Tags: monitor

A few months ago I was using my secondary monitor for some programming. It was "plug and play" type of connection. Yesterday I tried to connect it and got this artifact kind of view. The only things I tried was kernel downgrade and ubuntu reinstall. None of those worked. I am not sure about what drivers were installed before automatically.

Machine : Laptop; 
 - CPU : Ryzen 5 3550H; 
 - GPU : GTX 1050 3GB;

Trying to connect through HDMI.

The view that I get:

[image]

Monitor itself works on windows. Tried with other in work, same result.

HDMI plugged in:

```
 xrandr
 Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
1920x1080    120.00*+  48.00  
1680x1050    120.00  
1280x1024    120.00  
1440x900     120.00  
1280x800     120.00  
1280x720     120.00  
1024x768     120.00  
800x600      120.00  
640x480      120.00  
HDMI-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1920x1080     60.00 +  59.96    50.00    59.94    59.93  
1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
1680x1050     69.88    59.95    59.88  
1600x1024     60.17  
1400x1050     74.76    70.00    59.98  
1600x900      59.95    59.82  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1440x900      74.98    59.89    59.90  
1400x900      59.96    59.88  
1280x960      60.00  
1440x810      59.97  
1368x768      59.88    59.85  
1360x768      59.80    59.96  
1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.74  
1024x768      75.05    60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00  
960x720       75.00    60.00  
928x696       75.00    60.05  
896x672       75.05    60.01  
1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
etc..
```

Return of `sudo lshw -c display`

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:55 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Picasso
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: c2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:24 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7500000-f757ffff
```

Return of "About"

```
Memory 7.6GiB
Processor AMD Ryzen 5 3550h with radeon vega mobile gfx x 8
Graphics AMD Raven
GNOME 3.28.2
OS type 64-bit
Disk 82.1
```

Return of `uname -a`

```
Linux laptop 5.5.2-050502-generic #202002041931 SMP Tue Feb 4 19:33:15 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can provide any information needed, just tell me what kind of information you need.

Answer (score 0):

The xrandr command in Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) might help.

If you run xrandr by itself, it should show the name(s) of your monitors.

```
xrandr
```

What worked for me was this:

```
sudo xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1920x1200
```

where VGA-0 is the name of my secondary monitor and the mode value a good fit for my monitor.

If you ever mess up your resolution and can't read anything on the screen anymore, type (blindly) this command to reset it to a basic resolution:

```
sudo xrandr -s 1024x768
```

Comment: xrandr gives me "HDMI-1-1 connected 1600x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm" However running sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 1600x900 basically only restarted the monitor and it gave other colors

Answer (score 0):

Try working your way up to better resolutions starting with this:

sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 1024x768

Comment: If it would be a resolution problem, it wouldn't give any signal.